# Using the opencv stitcher module to stitch blurry images

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I am using python 3.5 and opencv 3.4.1.

I have a set of 19 images that I need to stitch. They are blurry and the stitching module is unable to stitch them. I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269798/opencv-3d-stitching-panorama/39284181#39284181), but am wondering if I can find a way to stitch. I would appreciate some specific suggestions and solutions. I want to stitch [these images](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mqhQDLEI5u0qWzTjG43k3TowvHW48cI-).

I have tried changing the match_conf as reccomended by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269798/opencv-3d-stitching-panorama/39284181#39284181). How would I edit this as the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp) states that it is a flag? I have tried using the line below to change the match_conf to 0.1, but it does not work and I get the error below.

```
stitcher = cv2.createStitcher(False) 
stitcher.setFeaturesMatcher(detail = BestOf2NearestMatcher(false, 0.1))
result = np.empty(shape=[2048, 2048])
ret, result = stitcher.stitch(imgs, result)
```

> 'cv2.Stitcher' object has no attribute 'setFeaturesMatcher'

Comment: This is what you can get with Microsoft ICE: [image](https://imgur.com/a/VdoSlZk) If you can, use a dedicated software to do the stitching. If you have to code it, this is not an easy task since the images are really blurry. You may want to use instead a software that has a command line interface.

Comment: Ok @Catree Thanks for the insight. I would like to see if anybody has any other suggestions before I use a software with command line interface.

Comment: This looks like microscope imagery, is the movement always guaranteed to be a planar panning motion?

Comment: @BHawk yes it is.

Comment: Your images look like frames from a video camera, complete with motion blur as the stage moves. I would capture sharp images (not video) on a regular grid, then assemble with a set of simple pairwise matches. Do you have computer control over your stage and camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404492/stitching-images-cant-detect-common-feature-points?noredirect=1&lq=1) out.
Possibly gig into pipeline and change opencv C++ code.

"This is full pipleline of OPencv Stitching code. You can see that there are lot of parameters you can change to make your code give some good stitching result. Also I would suggest using a small image (640 X480) for the feature detection step. Using small images is better than using very large images"

Technically you should be able to change the parameter from python, but hopeful somebody else knows how to do that.s